# PHP: Redirect back to index.html when php process dies

Tags: php, html, image, file-upload, upload

First of all, my php script is working but I want to add another feature.
When the process dies, it should redirect you back to the index.html.

How it works:

Upload .png file > php checks some criteria, if one is not reached, process dies and an echo is created.

```
<?php
$upload_folder = 'upload/'; //
$filename = pathinfo($_FILES['datei']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$extension = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['datei']['name'],      PATHINFO_EXTENSION));


//Checking if png is falid
$allowed_extensions = array('png');
if(!in_array($extension, $allowed_extensions)) {
 die("Only .png files are valid.");

}
```

I tried alot but it does not seem to work. Any Idea?

Comment: Do a redirect instead of a `die` then.

Comment: Wow. That's so obvious that I did not took it into account. I'm sorta stupid. Thank you.

Comment: The "how it works" shows how the process works at the moment. I did not want to spam the whole code, the code snippet at the bottom is just a sneak peak of the whole code with the process dieing but not redirecting.